# Determining elements in a group of order 8

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is non-abelian group of order 8, and it has an element $g \in G$ with order 4, and another element $f \in G$ that is not in $<g>$. How do I know that the elements are $e, g, g^2, g^3, f, fg, fg^2, fg^3$. Namely, how to prove that $f^2$ does not exist? (i.e. is just $e$) Do I just do it by trial and error?

Comment: No sorry, why is there only 2 cosets of <g>? and why does that imply $f^2$ is in <g>?

Comment: Thanks! I understand how to continue now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $|G|/|\langle g \rangle| = 2$, there are two cosets of $\langle g \rangle$ in $G$. These are $\langle g \rangle$ and $f\langle g \rangle$.

Now you can conclude that $f^{2}$ has to be in one of these two cosets. It can be seen that $f^{2} \not\in f\langle g \rangle = \{f, fg, fg^2, fg^3 \}$, so we must have $f^{2} \in \langle g \rangle = \{e, g, g^2, g^3 \}$.

I will let you continue from here.

Comment: Hello, the next part asks me to prove that fg^3 = gf, any idea you can provide to do this part?